# How to solve vim editing data files on multiple locations (eg: different devices)?

Tags: gvim

Sorry for my lousy title, feel free to improve it because i am not good at describing my issue.
I don't know how to use 1 sentence to describe my problem, hence lengthy text below. sorry.

1. I uses vim on several devices. (depend on which device i was using at different time during the activity i am doing, eg: when i am out in the field, i have to use droidvim on android, at home i am using vim on manjaro)
2. Hence the text files i am editing and appending will be scattered on multiple places (I don't do cloud thing, and gave up on syncthing app).
3. So, when i am at home, i uses sshfs to mount android to manjaro and hence uses vim to access the files on android like local file.
   ~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/'
   The problem:
4. So When i fire up vim from manjaro, i have default it to a specific data folder (with :cd ~/myDailyFolder in .vimrc) on manjaro pc, where files that i uses daily lies).
   I also have F6-F9 setup to launch the files with 1 button in vim (because i use those files daily).
5. Then i need the files in my sshfs mounted (android device) as well. The name of the files in android device is exactly the same (due to i uses syncthing lastime ~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/'before i gave up using it).
6. This is how i mount android . `$ sshfs -p 8022 u0_a402@192.168.0.37:/stora~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/'ge ~/sshfs-mount2 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/termux-rsa`

Note:

1. Folder location due to the above sshfs mount will now be   : '~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/0/myDailyFolder/' .
2. due to Android os permission issue (not rooted phone) , one can not access anything in '~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/' , but no problem with folder location '~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/0/' and beyond.

Everytime i need to access the files on manjaro pc, i can easily just open the files , be it with ':e myfile.txt' or with F6-F9 button.

The problem:

1. However when i need to access the files on android , i would have to type length location such: ':e ~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/0/myDailyFolder/myFile1.txt'.
2. I can't use tab to on when typing location on android, because it will not pass through ':e ~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/' due to NO permission to browse on the location on android.
3. NERDtree can't help too, because it also can't browse past through this location: '~/sshfs-mount2/emulated/'

Please give me suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Bind some convenient commands or keys to those paths? I think this boils down to "I have mappings for a convenient set of files, but equivalently named files in a different directory can't be tab-completed; how can I conveniently access those?"

Comment: I did just as what you said.  It works great. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to self-answer

Comment: I don't get you . .. you meant to close this thread ?

Comment: I mean: if you have an answer to the question, post it down in the "answer" section.